# retrieve all child node from firebase with AngularFire as Array

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I get the result returned from Firebase as Array with hierarchy as below:

```
[
  [
    {name: "a", id: 1},
    {name: "b", id: 2},
    {name: "c", id: 3}
  ],
  [
    {name: "d", id: 1},
    {name: "e", id: 2}
  ]
]
```

How can I list out every name from that hierarchy to use for ng-repeat? 
I can list names of each array with $asArray() but I can't retrieve them in all array. And can I get the index of each array as variable?
This is my ng-repeat:

```
<ul ng-repeat="cha in character">
   <li href="/link/{{each_array_index(1,2,3...)}}/{{cha.id}}">{{cha.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: At first glance, this data structure does not make any sense, particularly for Firebase, which [stores data as JSON objects](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html) and provides real-time editing. These arrays are actually objects, cannot be ordered as JSON data, and generally won't work with concurrency. Can you explain the use case for this data structure and why it was necessary over push ids or a flat list?

Comment: I create flat and nested model of data. I have 3 levels (cat -> topics -> content). Therefore, if I want to retrieve the content, I need to have the id/title of category & topics to push into Firebase path

Answer (score 1):

you need to have two nested repeaters, in your expression 'cha in character', cha contains an array of objects; you should have something like

ng-repeat='sublist in lists'

ng-repeat='character in sublist'

alternatively you could flatten the array response you are recieving

```
var xs = [
  [
    {name: "a", id: 1},
    {name: "b", id: 2},
    {name: "c", id: 3}
  ],
  [
    {name: "d", id: 4},
    {name: "e", id: 5}
  ]
];

var merged = [];
merged = merged.concat.apply(merged, xs);
```

or you could create a filter

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

  .controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.xs = [
  [
    {name: "a", id: 1},
    {name: "b", id: 2},
    {name: "c", id: 3}
  ],
  [
    {name: "d", id: 4},
    {name: "e", id: 5}
  ]
];
  })

  .filter('flatten', function(){
    return function(xs) {
      var merged = [];
      return merged.concat.apply(merged, xs);
    }
  })
  ;




<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    <ul ng-repeat="cha in xs | flatten">
     <li><a href="/link/{{$index}}/{{cha.id}}">{{cha.name}} - {{cha.id}}</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
```

THE NESTED LIST SOLUTION
described in comments

```
<ul ng-repeat="list in xs">
     <li ng-repeat="cha in list">
       <a href="/link/{{$parent.$index}}/{{cha.id}}">{{cha.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @JackNova. I love to use 2 repeaters. now I can list out every name, but I only define $index for character, I can't find $index for sublist. How can I get this?

Comment: I need to keep the $index of each parent array to retrieve the content based on REST. The links should be: #/link/1/1, #/link/1/2, #link/1/3, #link/2/1, #link/2/2..

Comment: the outer $index will be in $parent.$index

Comment: the $parent.$index returns number as $index: #link/1/1, #link/2/2, #link/3/3... They should be #link/1/1, #link/1/2...

Comment: the leftmost is the $parent.$index, the rightmost is the $index